# How to generate JSON examples from OpenAPI 3.0 specification

Tags: json, yaml, swagger-2.0, openapi

I'm trying to generate Json examples from OpenAPI specifications by using swagger parser, the problem is that when I try to run my code it returns an exception for the following line :
 Map < String, Schema > definitions = swagger.getComponents().getSchemas();

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.parser.OpenAPIV3Parser;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.oas.inflector.examples.models.Example;
import io.swagger.oas.inflector.examples.ExampleBuilder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import io.swagger.oas.inflector.processors.JsonNodeExampleSerializer;
import io.swagger.util.Json;
import java.util.Map;

public class essai {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OpenAPI swagger = new OpenAPIV3Parser().read("C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\openapi.yaml");
            Map < String, Schema > definitions = swagger.getComponents().getSchemas();
            Schema model = definitions.get("Pet");
            Example example = ExampleBuilder.fromSchema(model, definitions);
            SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule().addSerializer(new JsonNodeExampleSerializer());
            Json.mapper().registerModule(simpleModule);
            String jsonExample = Json.pretty(example);
            System.out.println(jsonExample);
}
}
```

The error message is :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.demo.essai.main(essai.java:16)

Comment: Does your YAML file contain the `components` section and the `schemas` section inside it?

Comment: No it doesn't contain any of these sections

Comment: I just added these sections and it works now , Thank you !